# Can I file taxes on a home based business and deduct expenses even if I don't generate income?

Tags: taxes

If I had a Home Based Business and generated no income but had many expenses, can I file taxes?   My expenses consisted of travel, dinner meetings with potential clients, etc. 
Can I file these deductions/credits even though I did not generate any income?

Comment: In what country is the business?

Comment: By "file taxes" I assume you mean "take a tax deduction". You should always file a tax return.

Comment: @Rocky not necessarily. In the US - there's an income threshold below which you're not required to file a tax return.

Comment: By "you" I meant OP, not everyone.

Comment: How do you know what the OP has to do or should do? You don't even know what country he's from.

Comment: If this is the US, are you filing it as a separate business entity, or as a Schedule C?  My understanding on the Schedule C is that you can file it for a couple of years at a loss, and then if you can't bring it to profit, it's considered a 'hobby' and not a business.  (based on advice I was given in a similar situation ~20 years ago ... I'm not putting this as an official answer as it might have changed since then).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the US, if a human assessor audited you, could you show a future profit motive or will they conclude you are expensing a hobby?

If you answer yes, you are likely to only be deducting limited expenses this year, carrying forward losses to your profitable years.  See the examples in pub 535: http://www.irs.gov/publications/p535/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000208633

Answer (score 0):

In the US, you can only take a tax deduction on expenses to the extent that they offset income. For an S corp or LLC, if the business had no income, there's no deduction to take. If you have a sole proprietorship, these expenses can offset other income.

You can also carry-forward net operating losses to future years when you have more income.

See the article [How to Carry Over Business Expenses](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/carry-over-business-expenses-19247.html)

Comment: That is not true at all, you can definitely deduct business losses in the US.

Comment: Still wrong....

Comment: Enlighten me, please.

Comment: Hmm... You **can** deduct LLC/S-Corp business losses, just the same as sole proprietorship. In fact, LLC is disregarded for tax purposes at all, and doesn't matter whatsoever. Here, you're enlightened.

Comment: not feeling it, but thanks anyway